# How to create a foreign key to columns of an ElementCollection in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys

Given the following class model:

```java
package demo;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Embeddable
class Address {
  String street;
}

@Embeddable
class AddressDetails {
  byte[] photo;
}

@MappedSuperclass
abstract class User {
  @Id Long id;
  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) Set<Address> addresses;
  @ElementCollection Map<Address, AddressDetails> addressDetails; // wanted: FK to addresses
}

@Entity
class Sub1 extends User {}

@Entity
class Sub2 extends User {}
```

I'm trying to tell JPA that `addressDetails` references rows from `addresses`. How can I do that?

This is the foreign key constraint that **I'd like to convert to annotations**:

```sql
ALTER TABLE sub1_address_details
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_sub1_address_address_details
        FOREIGN KEY (sub1_id, address_id)
            REFERENCES sub1_addresses
            ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

This is the foreign key constraint that **Hibernate generates** currently:

```sql
    alter table vblife_pv.sub1_addresses 
       add constraint FKdm58cvoq5gqndtlpr4t7auyct 
       foreign key (sub1_id) 
       references sub1
```

I tried to add

```java
@CollectionTable(joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(table = "addresses", referencedColumnName = "id")})
```

to `addressDetails`, but this does not change Hibernate's DDL output.

I'm using Hibernate 5.4.21.

Comment: The whole idea of `ElementCollection` is to use basic types without too much JPA mapping but if you want to use `Address` as a proper entity (with a `@OneToMany` relationship to `AddressDetails`) then using an `ElementCollection` does not make any sense.

Comment: This example is a simplification of a real business case. Address is strongly dependent on User, and AddressDetails is a per-user addition to Address. Neither Address nor AddressDetails make sense outside the context of a User and thus have no identity.

Comment: That well may be but that's not the point of `ElementCollection` and simulating that behaviour is from my point of view much more effort than making `Address` an entity referring to an `ElementCollection` of `AddressDetails`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want that, you should probably use the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
public class UserAddress {
    @EmbeddedId
    UserAddressId id;
    @ManyToOne(LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    Address address;
    @ManyToOne(LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    User user;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userAddress")
    AddressDetails details;
}
@Embeddable
public class UserAddressId {
    int addressId;
    int userId;
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "address_details")
public class AddressDetails {
    @EmbeddedId
    UserAddressId id;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumn = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumn = "address_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    UserAddress userAddress;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I realized too late that the foreign key constraint that I was looking for is not valid (from a business logic point of view), so I can't verify if your suggestion would solve my problem.